# LiDAR data is displaying in wrong position

Tags: arcmap, lidar

I spent most of today, unsuccessfully, trying to understand a LiDAR dataset.  The dataset is from the Texas Natural Resources Information System and is identified as the Buffalo Bayou elevation LiDAR set.  (https://data.tnris.org/collection/431979b1-6b75-4aaf-b020-380c0a4e9e76). It came as LAZ files which I used the free LASTools software to convert to LAS files.  I turned all of these into an LAS Dataset successfully.

However, the outlines for the datasets display half a county away from their actual location based on regional state and county data sets from both Texas and Houston. I installed the tool called "3D Sample Tools".  I assumed after the install I could use them but they all fail so I could not create a prj file.  As a result I am stumped!

Any suggestions on how to move these data? It almost feels like the XYs are incorrectly projected or it is the incorrect projection to begin with. Just for clarity this is Buffalo Bayou data which should run directly through the center of the roads above it in the picture.

[image]

Comment: Here is the CRS for the LAZ files. https://epsg.io/6588. What CRS is your final data in?  What is the CRS of the road data?  What is the CRS of the map frame you are using?

Comment: I did try that before entering my question.  Result was that either it is in the wrong zone or the coordinates for that zone are in error.